# Wordpress Taxonomies ussuage

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

Can someone explain why I should use taxonomies on my site? I dont really understand the benefits of it. I'm new on wordpress and Ive read the codex.. Dont feel the need to over do your answer just a few lines so I can get a small understanding.

Thank you

Comment: Read the description of that [wordpress] tag. Such question is better asked in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small example: I build websites for wineries. Some want to have navigation by wine style, e.g. a list of links to products that are "red", "white", "sparkling", "fortified", etc. I could use tags for that, but by creating a custom taxonomy I'm able to give the URLs a slug "style" instead of "tag", hence "example.com/style/red" and "example.com/style/white".

Answer (score 2):

A taxonomy is a way of grouping/sorting your posts or custom post types. I used them recently on a real estate website, here is what I had:

- Wordpress posts are the articles on the blog
- I created a "listing" custom type with the same features as posts

My taxonomies are the following (they have categories behaviour):
- Places
- Type: condo, house or commercial
- Wordpress categories are for the blog.

Comment: could you give me the website adress? want to check it out. thank you

Answer (score 1):

The taxonomies are good for SEO. It is a good way to find the content of your website. Also, you can use links to help your user. Clicking on this linki, he could se a list of content with that taxonomy.